# I want that image popup in html when user click on tumbnil

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want that when user click on image thumbnil then the image popup just like it does in this [click here](http://www.alpacafarmingguide.com/why.htm)

plesase tell me the simplest way to do this as i am new to web development.
please help me out I am waiting for you kind response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of the [lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) plugins for this.  There are some other versions out there as well, for example [here](http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-lightbox/demo/) and [here](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/).

The usages will vary slightly, but there are examples on each of the sites above.  You can google for more, just search for "[javascript lightbox](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+lightbux)" or "[jquery lightbox](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+lightbux)" for more examples.

Answer (score 5):

That kind of thing is called a Modal Popup (modal because it prevents interaction with the rest of the page.)  There are quite a few implementations available.  The [JQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and the [Lightbox](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) are some of the better ones.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at is a modal pop up window:
http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial

Above is a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at jQuery for this one. www.jquery.com
Load the jquery library followed by a light box component. There are plenty of these if you Google 'jquery lightbox' you will find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). It's very easy to use

Answer (score 0):

I implemented here

```
http://www.art.com/gallery/id--b1822/abstract-posters.htm?ui=9E23F1D932F54F2F8F2E37851C860158
```

mouseover any image , i show big image.

Let me know if you want , i can give you the code

```
http://www.allposters.com/-st/Animal-Posters_c622_.htm
```

change to grid view and mouseover image

It should very simple , you can need to have the big image ready and create the html with big image by metnioning the max height and max width

and show the div with a bigger z-index. Thats it.